# samsung galaxy s3 media query conflicts with media query max-width:480px

Tags: media-queries

want to adjust the two buttons on this link http://screencast.com/t/FhNIYgSNcfE to be like the one mentioned below

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 380px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    nav ul li a.try_now{ border:solid 1px #06a1d1;  padding:0px 45px;}
    nav ul li a.buy_now{ border:solid 1px #f49000; padding:0px 42px;}
    nav ul li a.log_in{ border:solid 1px #000; position:relative; behavior:url(PIE.php); border-radius:5px; -o-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; padding:2px 130px 5px 125px; line-height:23px; font-size:13px; background:url(../images/inner-images/log_in.png) repeat-x;}
    nav ul li a.log_in span.lock{ background:url(../images/inner-images/lock.png) no-repeat; width:11px; height:17px; float:left; position:absolute; left:35%; top:25%; padding:0 10px 0 0;}

}


@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    nav ul li a.try_now{ border:solid 1px #06a1d1;  padding:0px 86px;}
    nav ul li a.buy_now{ border:solid 1px #f49000; padding:0px 72px;}
    nav ul li a.log_in{ border:solid 1px #000; position:relative; behavior:url(PIE.php); border-radius:5px; -o-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; padding:2px 130px 5px 125px; line-height:23px; font-size:13px; background:url(../images/inner-images/log_in.png) repeat-x;}
    nav ul li a.log_in span.lock{ background:url(../images/inner-images/lock.png) no-repeat; width:11px; height:17px; float:left; position:absolute; left:35%; top:25%; padding:0 10px 0 0;}
}
```

here is the link:

http://dev.ixod.com/contracts/ixod/level1.html

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain what exactly your problem is? You haven't provided any context here.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/FhNIYgSNcfE

Comment: like this http://screencast.com/t/FhNIYgSNcfE

Comment: as i am testing on http://www.responsinator.com i am countering this issue for Android (Samsung Galaxy) portrait 380 by 685 (equivalent desktop resolution)